# How to modify values which are one row below the values that meet a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, where-clause

Is there an efficient way to change the value of a previous row whenever a conditional is met in a subsequent entry? Specifically I am wondering if there is anyway to adapt pandas.where to modify the entry in a row prior or subsequent to the conditional test.  Suppose

```
Data={'Energy':[12,13,14,12,15,16],'Time':[2,3,4,2,5,6]}    
DF = pd.DataFrame(Data)

DF
Out[123]: 
   Energy  Time
0      12     2
1      13     3
2      14     4
3      12     2
4      15     5
5      16     6
```

If I wanted to change the value of Energy to 'X' whenever Time <= 2 I could just do something like.

```
DF['ENERGY']=DF['ENERGY'].where(DF['TIME'] >2,'X')
```

or

```
DF.loc[DF['Time']<=2,'Energy']='X'
```

Which would output

```
    Energy  Time
0      X     2
1     13     3
2     14     4
3      X     2
4     15     5
5     16     6
```

But what if I want to change the value of 'Energy' in the row after Time <=2 so that the output would actually be.

```
    Energy  Time
0     12     2
1      X     3
2     14     4
3     12     2
4      X     5
5     16     6
```

Is there an easy modification for a vectorized approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift the values one row down using [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and then compare:

```
df.loc[df['Time'].shift() <= 2, 'Energy'] = 'X'
df

  Energy  Time
0     12     2
1      X     3
2     14     4
3     12     2
4      X     5
5     16     6
```

Side note: I assume 'X' is actually something else here, but FYI, mixing strings and numeric data leads to `object` type columns which is a known pandas anti-pattern.